# Google Elevation API - Surface Height from 3D Overlay?

Tags: python, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-elevation-api

I been playing around with Google Maps Elevation API and have played around with the example [Python code](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/elevation/intro#CreatingElevationCharts).

There are plenty of places visible in Google Earth/Maps where there are 3D overlays (I guess from photogrammetry). For example, Ferndown Industrial Estate ( 50°48'41.75"N,   1°54'59.85"W) has some regular industrial buildings projected in 3D. If I probe around with the Elevation API here I would expect to find building heights returned. I don't, I just get some pretty constant ground heights.

Can anyone tell me how to access the building heights through Google APIs? Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

The Google Maps Elevation API provides you a simple interface to query locations on the earth for elevation data. Additionally, you may request sampled elevation data along paths, allowing you to calculate elevation changes along routes. As discussed in [The Google Maps Elevation API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/elevation/intro) documentation, it provides elevation data for all locations on the surface of the earth including depth locations on the ocean floor but does not mention access to building heights.

However, it is possible to measure most building heights much more accurately using the built-in tools that come with Google Earth Pro as discussed in [Google Earth and Maps documentation](https://www.google.com.ph/work/earthmaps/earthpro-features.html).

Comment: And of course the free trial link doesn't work! https://geoauth.google.com/gev0/free_trial.html

Comment: You may refer instead to [Start using Earth Pro](https://support.google.com/earth/answer/176160?hl=en) to try Google Earth Pro.